# Can`t use HOps addon

Tags: add-on

I tried several versions of this addon none of them worked. I even switched (not because of that) from windows 7 to windows 10. I`m using blender 2.92.0. Mamma Mia pizza macaroni

```
Report: Error
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users
AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\BoxCutter\addon\operator'shape\draw.py", line 494, in invoke
hit, self. ray['location'], self. ray['normal'], *_ = ray. cast. objects(*self.mouse['location'')
File "C:\Users\ AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender'2.92\scriptscrddons\BoxCutter\addon\utility/ray.py", line 57, in objects
hit, location, normal, index, object, matrix = bpy. context. scene. ray_cast(bpy. context. view layer, origin, direction)
TypeError: Scene. ray_cast(): error with argument 1, "depsgraph" - Function. depsgraph expected a Depsgraph type, not ViewLayer
location: <unknown location>:-1
```

[image: wtf is this]

Comment: Hello, as a wild guess I would say there is a version mismatch between the expected Blender version to be used with the addon and the one you're using. Make sure they are the same. Not all add-ons will work out of the bat with newer versions because there may be changes in the scripting interface.

Comment: Agree with @Gorgious, make sure it's the latest version of HardOps...